# Weird name in zsh terminal

Tags: zsh

This question has probably been asked and answered, but I can't seem to find any post that resolve my issue – mostly due to my lack of searching skills. So I apologize if my post is a duplicate and would appriecate if you either refer me to another post or answer my simple question.

When I first open -zsh terminal on my macOS, I am used to seeing the following prompt.

`(base) kimsan@Kims-MacBook-Pro ~ %`

On rare occasions, however, I see a totally random sequence of characters after @. For example,

`(base) kimsan@MDOM10FX ~ %`

As I said, the sequence of characters followed by @ is – or seem to me, at least – random; thus, changes everytime. Above is just one instance of example.

Why is this???

It has been a while since I first noticed this issue. I freaked out at first thinking that I messed something up with my system memory – which, in hindsight, is not even possible. Now, I think of it as some random inconsequential glitch that don't cause any harm. Nonetheless, I would be more comfortable knowing the cause of such glitch.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Perhaps covered by [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/662490/my-macos-hostname-changed-randomly-should-i-be-worried)? What happens if you enter `hostname`?

Comment: Is it possible that you've been connected to VPN when the weird hostname appeared?